# Dask 'distributed.comm.tcp - INFO - Connection closed before handshake completed'

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I deployed a Dask service to my K8s cluster with one scheduler, three workers, and one client connecting to the scheduler. When I connect to the scheduler (`kubectl attach <my-scheduler-pod>`), I get constant stdout messages consisting of:

```
distributed.comm.tcp - INFO - Connection closed before handshake completed
```

This shows up with four messages every six seconds or so. The four messages come in pretty close to each other. As far as I can tell, this isn't adversely affecting anything -- my service *is* running -- but the message itself as well as the constant nature doesn't seem to be a good thing.

What, if anything, should I do about this?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the dash scheduler is running on a different dask version

```
from distributed.versions import get_versions
get_versions()
```

I replicated the same issue in local
My dask scheduler is running on dask 2021.01.0 where as my client using 2021.0.1.03

Dask scheduler :-
`{'host': {'python': '3.8.0.final.0', 'python-bits': 64, 'OS': 'Linux', 'OS-release': '4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64', 'machine': 'x86_64', 'processor': '', 'byteorder': 'little', 'LC_ALL': 'C.UTF-8', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8'}, 'packages': {'python': '3.8.0.final.0', 'dask': '2021.01.0', 'distributed': '2021.01.0', 'msgpack': '1.0.0', 'cloudpickle': '1.6.0', 'tornado': '6.1', 'toolz': '0.11.1', 'numpy': '1.18.1', 'lz4': '3.1.1', 'blosc': '1.9.2'}}`

Client:-
`{'host': {'python': '3.7.10.final.0', 'python-bits': 64, 'OS': 'Linux', 'OS-release': '4.14.214-160.339.amzn2.x86_64', 'machine': 'x86_64', 'processor': '', 'byteorder': 'little', 'LC_ALL': 'C.UTF-8', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8'}, 'packages': {'python': '3.7.10.final.0', 'dask': '2021.03.0', 'distributed': '2021.03.0', 'msgpack': '1.0.2', 'cloudpickle': '1.6.0', 'tornado': '6.1', 'toolz': '0.11.1', 'numpy': None, 'lz4': None, 'blosc': None}`

Make sure both are running the same version.